# add a GUI class/control to object library of Interface Builder

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder

I have created a subclass of NSButton.
Is it possible to add the GUI class/control to object library  of Interface Builder.
If sure, is there any tutorial?

Welcome any comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is just to make IB create an instance of your class instead of an NSButton then you can just drag an NSButton onto the window like normal, and change the class name in the Identity Inspector pane.

It is possible to add your control to the object library, I believe you need to create an IBPalette.

Comment: You can only create interfaces for custom objects in Interface Builder versions less than 4.0. Xcode 4 does not support Interface Builder customisation, unfortunately. File a bug if you want this to change.

Comment: Also, note that when editing a nib file it’s possible to specify user-defined properties, which can be handy when the subclass defines extra properties that are not settable via the standard inspector.